# MonoTouch - Multiple .strings files

Tags: localization, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement multiple .strings files in Monotouch project and each .strings file has the localization string of each UI. The localization strings in the file Localizable.strings seems working in Monotouch (which is default), but when I try to get the value from another .strings it returns key . I am using the method MonoTouch.Foundation.NSBundle.LocalizedString("Key","","Table") where table is the .strings file name. Anyone had luck on getting values from different .strings file in Monotouch? Pls advise.

Thanks,
Shan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how it is working. The table name you provide is not meant for other languages, but for specific localization files of the current language. An example will make it clearer:

en/Localizable.strings contains:
"Hello" = "Hi!";
"World" = "World!";

To get "Hello", you use `LocalizedString("Hello").`
To get "World", you use `LocalizedString("World").`

If now you find a reason to split your localization file, you could do that:

en/Localizable.strings contains:
"Hello" = "Hi!";

en/OtherStrings.strings:
"World" = "World!";

In this case:

To get "Hello", you use `LocalizedString("Hello")`.
To get "World", you use `LocalizedString("World", "", "OtherStrings")`.